# Многоуровневый Binding

Tags: wpf, xaml

Вью-модель содержит список с книгами `ObservableCollection<Book>`

```
public class VM
{ 
    public ObservableCollection<Book> bookList { get; set; } 
}
```

`книга` в свою очередь содержит `список с рассказами`

```
public class Book
{ 
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public ObservableCollection<Story> storyList { get; set; } 
}
```

Рассказ имеет название и количество страниц

```
public class Story
{ 
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int CountPage {get;set;} 
}
```

Вопрос в том как правильно привязаться к свойствам `Name` и `CountPage`?

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding bookList}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Рассказ" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Количество страниц" Binding="{Binding CountPage}"/>              
    </DataGrid.Columns>                   
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Всё зависит от того, как именно Вы хотите отобразить содержимое. В книге много рассказов, у каждого рассказа своё количество страниц. Думаю, DataGrid, тут не совсем подходит, Вам, скорее, нужен TreeView. Либо включайте TreeView в Details каждого Row из DataGrid(т.е. каждой книги). Можете использовать HierachicalDataTemplate.

Answer (score 2):

Можете попробовать что-нибудь в таком духе:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding bookList}">
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding storyList}">
                <TreeView.Resources>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CountPage}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.Resources>
            </TreeView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Рассказ" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Количество страниц" Binding="{Binding CountPage}"/>              
    </DataGrid.Columns>                   
</DataGrid>
```

Сам шаблон для Details оформите, конечно, сами (как-нибудь более приглядно). Но думаю, на общую идею этот код Вас должен натолкнуть.

P.S. `public`-свойства Вашей `ViewModel` лучше именовать с прописной буквы. Со строчной буквы, как правило, именуют закрытые поля.

Comment: идея с rowdetailtemplate понятна, но в данном случае чтобы работал `detail` необходимо вывести список книг для начала, ведь он отображается по нажатию строку. А для этого нужно к чему то привязаться от самого bookList,

Comment: Ну если Вам нужно, чтобы сразу выводилось всё дерево - используйте сразу `TreeView` без `DataGrid`. И установите `IsExpanded` в `true`. В Ваших модельных классах так или иначе просматривается иерархическая структура.

Comment: отпишусь когда попробую, спасибо

Comment: сделал полностью через TreeView это мне помогло, ваша идея верная, но код с ошибками.

Comment: @S.KosT, в студии не проверял, поэтому возможны неточности в коде разметки. Рад, что Вам помогло.